# Should these privileges work for my new mysql user

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, privileges

I want to make a new user for mysql that my website should connect with.

My website uses the following functions:

SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT, INNER JOIN.

My website is also using mysqli with bind_param/prepared statements, and also supports image upload, with a crop function.

So should the following privileges work for a new user in order to use the stuff above

SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT, FILE.

And I am not sure if I need the "EXECUTE" and "INDEX" privilege.

I already have a root user which I use to change around in the database with, I only want this new user to be used BY my website.

ALSO, I am creating this user using the program Sequel Pro, should I manually run a "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" after adding the user and setting privileges or does Sequel Pro do that for me?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You don't need `FILE` (that upload is just an `INSERT`), `INNER JOIN` isn't a privilege,  I would bet good money `SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT` is all you need. I don't know Sequel Pro, so I can't answer that part.

Comment: thanks, I will just try it soon my server is set.